# Comparison of normal coordinates in two nearby points

Tags: differential-geometry

Given two points $x,y \in M$ in some Riemannian manifold $ (M,g) $ with distance $d(x,y)< \frac{inj}{2}$, where $inj$ is the injectivity radius of $(M,g)$, and some orthonormal basis $v_1 , \ldots , v_n$ of $T_x M$ we get a basis $i_{\ast}v_1 , \ldots , i_{\ast}v_n$ of $T_y M$.

Now we can choose a normal coordinate system $(\phi_1, U_x)$ in $x $ and 
a normal coordinate system $(\phi_2, U_y) $ in $y$ with respect to these orthonormal bases.

Is there a way to compute for $z \in U_x \cap U_y$ the difference $ \phi_1(z) - \phi_2(z)$? I suspect that it holds something like
$$
|\phi_1(z) - \phi_2(z) |= d(x,y) + \mathcal{O}(d(x,y)^2+ d(x,z)^2 + d(z,y)^2)
$$
I am looking for a reference or a tip how tackle this problem.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. You have the letter $i$ appearing as a distance and as a mapping.

Comment: I edited it, the i in $i$ as distence is supposed to be the injecity radius of $(M,g).